# Converter Array em String

Tags: php

Por que quando faço a conversão do array para uma string ele não converte todas as chaves do array certinho:

Codigo:

```
<?php

        $bMsg3 = array(
            $at1 = 0,   /* Inteiro */
            $at2 = "",  /* String */
            $at3 = 0.0,  /* Float */
            $at4 = 0  /* Float */
        );

        $bMsg3[$at1] = 400;
        $bMsg3[$at2] = "Hello World!";
        $bMsg3[$at3] = 3.14;
        $bMsg3[$at4] = 200.0;


        // Converte para string
        $str = implode(':', $bMsg3);

        print "String: $str";

        ?>
```

O resultado é:
String: 200::0:0:Hello World!

Na qual deveria ser: 400:Hello World!:3.14:200.0

Alguém sabe o motivo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O resultado não é o esperado porque você está fazendo várias atribuições na mesma chave.

Basicamento todas as variáveis tem o valor zero, exceto `$at2`. Na atribuições você passa o valor da zero praticamento todas as vezes exceto `$at2`

```
    $bMsg3 = array($at1 = 0, $at2 = "", $at3 = 0.0, $at4 = 0);


    $bMsg3[$at1] = 400;
    $bMsg3[$at2] = "Hello World!";
    $bMsg3[$at3] = 3.14;
    $bMsg3[$at4] = 200.0;

    //As atribuições acima são equivalentes a:
    $bMsg3[0] = 400;
    $bMsg3[""] = "Hello World!";
    $bMsg3[0] = 3.14;
    $bMsg3[0] = 200.0;
```

[Exemplo passo a passo - ideone](https://ideone.com/wAG2Ai)

---

### Sobre a definição de chaves/índices e resultados curiosos

O manual descreve o comportamento de como devem ser definidas as chaves de um array:

- As chaves devem ser strings ou inteiros somente.
- Strings que contém valores inteiros serão convertidas para integer DESDE que válidas.
  O manual sugere o exemplo que `"8"`(string) será convertido em `8`(int) e `08`(int) não porque não é um decimal válido.
  Não fica evidente que numeros iniciados com zero são octais, se válidos representam outro valor decimal. Se precisar manter o zero a esquerda em alguma índice número a forma de garantir isso é colocar o valor entre aspas como uma string.

Talvez por isso programadores confundam tanto o dia das bruxas com o natal :).

Ex: 1

```
$arr = array(031 => 'dezembro');
Saída: 
Array ( [25] => dezembro )
```

Ex: 2

```
$arr = array('031' => 'dezembro');
Saída:
Array( [031] => dezembro )
```

- Floats são convertidos em inteiros, isso significa que apenas a parte inteira do número será convertida em uma chave.
- Booleans são convertidos em inteiros 0 para false e 1 para true.
- Nulls são convertidos para uma string vazia.
- Arrays e objetos não podem ser usados como chaves, isso lançara um warning: Illegal offset type.
- Se vários elementos usam a mesma chave, apenas o último valor será considerado os demais são sobrescritos.

Exemplo sobre os itens 3 e 7.

```
$arr = [0.1 => 'a', 0.2 =>'b', 0.3 =>'c'];
echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr);
```

Saída:

```
Array
(
    [0] => c
)
```

[Manual - arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: O segredo é "passar" um `float` como `string` se é intencional usar as chaves assim sendo :)

Answer (score 4):

No php, a função `implode` não funciona para chaves, mas apenas para os valores do `array`.

Exemplo:

```
$array = ['site' => 'stackoverlow', 'linguagem' => 'portugues']

implode(',', $array); // string: stackoverflow, portugues
```

## Como se atribui um array ou varíaveis em grupo?

Agora, a primeira parte do seu código parece ter um erro, já que você não pode atribuir assim:

```
$bMsg3 = array(
            $at1 = 0,   /* Inteiro */
            $at2 = "",  /* String */
            $at3 = 0.0,  /* Float */
            $at4 = 0  /* Float */
        );
```

Mas apenas assim (com o `=>`):

```
$bMsg3 = array(
            $at1 => 0,   /* Inteiro */
            $at2 => "",  /* String */
            $at3 => 0.0,  /* Float */
            $at4 => 0  /* Float */
        );
```

A não ser que você quis fazer uma atribuição para os valores da chaves em massa. Aí deveria ficar assim:

```
 $at1 = 0;
 $at2 = "";
 $at3 = 0.0;
 $at4 = 0;
```

Ou assim:

```
list($at1, $at2, $at3, $at4) = array(0, "", 0.0, 0);
```

## Observação importante!

No PHP, os valores aceitos para índices de `arrays` são apenas inteiros e strings. Valores como `float` não são aceitos.

Vi isso na prova do ZEND:

```
$array[1.0] = 1;
$array[1.1] = 1.1;

count($array); // retorna 1
```

Confira no [IDEONE](http://ideone.com/KlQ03s)

O que pode ser feito é criar uma representação para o valor `float` através de uma string.

Assim:

```
$array['0.0'] = 0;
```

Answer (score 4):

Faz assim =

```
    $bMsg3[] = 400;
    $bMsg3[] = "Hello World!";
    $bMsg3[] = 3.14;
    $bMsg3[] = 200.0; 

    // Converte para string
    $str = implode(':', $bMsg3);

    print "String: $str";
    ?>
```

Resultado = String: 400:Hello World!:3.14:200

Comment: Simples e objetivo :)

Answer (score -4):

Você poderia fazer da seguinte forma:

```
    <?php
function mapped_implode($glue, $array, $symbol = '=') {
    return implode($glue, array_map(
            function($k, $v) use($symbol) { 
                return $k . $symbol . $v;
            }, 
            array_keys($array), 
            array_values($array)
            )
        );
}

$arr = [
    0 => 400, 
    '' => "Hello World!", 
    '0.0' => 3.14,
    1 => 200.0,
];

echo mapped_implode(', ', $arr, ' is ');
```

> Console: 0 is 400,  is Hello World!, 0.0 is 3.14, 1 is 200

Tentei fazer no máximo possível exatamente como vc publicou, somente não consegui aplicar os 0.0 floats no final do array devido a replicação com a primeira chave já que 0.0 corresponde a 0 no PHP, a solução para isso seria outro valor diferente de 0 ou 0.0